# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an application where user sells or buys used items. In my first activity, I have grid view where I show thumbnail images and when user clicks on an image and then it takes him to detail activity. I use back button to go back to main activity page. It works fine but crashes if I click on 8-9 images and getting out of memory(OOM).

**CustomVolleyRequest Class**

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

Memory Monitoring, each click increments, it does free the memory when I go back to main activity!

[image]

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask  E/AndroidRuntime: 
Process: PID: 5700 
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
doInBackground()  E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)  E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:627)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 com.example.xxx.xxx.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:26)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 com.example.xxx.xxx.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:14)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: share the code please

Comment: I have shared the code

Comment: What I understand from your log is that you are downloading images and showing them in an `ImageView` and the crash happens because they are too large in size and the app cannot handle it. Try resizing them to lower resolutions before setting them to `ImageView`s

Comment: I resized them in the server already.

Comment: _"Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"_ Either add memory or reduce the size of the image you are loading.

Comment: Resizing them at client side really helps. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/5352802

Comment: @JimGarrison, I have just added my `CustomVolley Request` Class as well in my question. Do you see anything wrong over there? How could I increase memory ?

Comment: Well I have never used Volley so can't say about that. The answer I gave you the link to explains how to downscale an image based on it's original resolution so as to it doesn't throw `OutOfMemoryException` while settings those images to `ImageView`s

Comment: But it does not happen for certain image, it happens randomly after I click 8-9 images. It seems it is caching clicked images somewhere and then becomes out of memory error. When user click on back button , I guess it stores all the visited pages, I believe I should clear them up. Do not you think so?

Comment: Please see my memory plot in my updated question, it clearly indicates each time I go back it does not free up the memory. It stays over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the logs, look at this line:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

It clearly says that app is crashing just because of `OutOfMemoryError` exception. One possible reason might be you are handling large size bitmaps without downscaling them. You need to resize and downscale your bitmap before setting them to image views.

For more details on how to manage bitmap effectively, see official [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: But it does not happen for certain image, it happens randomly after I click 8-9 images. It seems it is caching clicked images somewhere and then throws out of memory error. When I click on back button , I guess it stores all the visited pages, I believe I should clear them up. Do not you think so? If you agree, how I should clear them up?

Comment: It totally depends upon how much available RAM you have to handle your images. If you have enough memory available, you would not get any crash. Still suggesting you to downscale bitmaps before processing them as there are high probability of getting crash on low-end devices.

Comment: Please see my memory plot in my updated question, it clearly indicates each time I go back it does not free up the memory. It stays over there.

Comment: As you can see, memory keeps growing on and at time 1m5sec, GC called to free-up some memory.

Comment: As I already mentioned, you need to downscale your images before processing them. Or, if you just wanna show images in image views, you can simply use image processing libraries like Picasso, Glide etc. Just define the image size (optional) and rest of the thing will be done by the library itself.

Comment: I am using Volley library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100440/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-texas).